# PostgreSQL: Run vacuumlo on a specific schema

Tags: postgresql, schema, vacuum

is it possible to run the vacuumlo tool only on a specific schema of a database?
I can only run it on a complete database, but that is not what i want.

Comment: No; you'll have to write your own queries.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.  LO are not schema-specific.

Comment: But are they not connected to a specific schema?